# z3 building java binding error

Tags: z3, java-binding

I got the error message below when compiling the z3 source code (37c9a31 commit) for Java binding on Mac.
The OS X I am using is El Capitan and the Java version is 1.8.0_91. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Another question: Is String currently supported in z3 Java binding compiled from the source? The latest release version(4.4.1) does not seem to support String.

```
"/usr/bin/javac" ../src/api/java/enumerations/*.java -d api/java/classes

"/usr/bin/javac" -cp api/java/classes ../src/api/java/*.java -d api/java/classes

../src/api/java/Sort.java:134: error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant
        case Z3_SEQ_SORT:
             ^

../src/api/java/Sort.java:136: error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant
        case Z3_RE_SORT:
             ^
../src/api/java/Expr.java:2179: error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant
        case Z3_SEQ_SORT:
             ^

../src/api/java/Expr.java:2181: error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant
        case Z3_RE_SORT:
             ^

4 errors
make: *** [com.microsoft.z3.jar] Error 1
```

Comment: Z3_SEQ_SORT was added recently. Did you try re-running python scripts/mk_make.py?

Comment: For the other question: Yes, strings are currently being added!

Comment: Yes, I did re-run the python script/mk_make.py...   The commands I used to compile the source are : python scripts/mk_make.py --java; cd build; make; @ChristophWintersteiger

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit, putting the error message in `code markdown`, hopefully making it more clear to visitors. Your question looks good, and seems to provide all the required information. If you have any more information that might help to solve it, please [edit] it into your question. For example, if you were able to build it on a different machine or using a diverent Java version. Good luck!

Comment: @paul I can't look at this right now, but can you please open a new issue in our issue tracker so we don't forget to fix this? (It's here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues )

Comment: I think this should be closed, because no-one can repro it.  It was also [moved to GitHub](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/672).